# How do I say "from this"/"this shows"? Like, "this shows you are lazy" or "from this I can tell you are lazy"

Tags: word-choice

See title. I'm looking for how this would be expressed in everyday speech, not in news reports (I know 由此可见 but that's too formal). More examples:

The way he walks shows that he is self-confident / From the way he walks, I can tell he is self-confident.
The first time I tried skiing I broke my leg. This shows I'm just not well suited to it.
Your dark tan tells me you like spending time outdoors.

Does the answer involve the word 表示? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that's too formal. Not every thing has both formal version and casual version, only a few of them.

Answer (score 2):

Words I can get are 看出(来)，说明，表明， 表示.  表明 and 表示 can be used in formal circumstances.

For example,

*this shows you are lazy*: 这说明/表明你很懒.

*from this I can tell you are lazy*: 从这可以看出你(很)懒.

*The way he walks shows that he is self-confident*: 他走路的样子说明他很自信.

*Your dark tan tells me you like spending time outdoors*: 你黝黑的肤色说明/表明你喜欢经常做户外活动。